# Как создать событие

Tags: javascript, ооп, coffeescript

Можно ли создать событие на динамически вставляемые элементы

```
el = document.querySelectorAll('.el1')[0]    

el.addEventListener('create', function() {
          console.log('добавился динамический элемент dive')
});
```

в **el** должен прилететь **div** не важно как он туда попадет но событие должно отработать

что тут нужно написать ?

```
var myEvent = new CustomEvent("create", {
      // ккакой то код
    });
```

Comment: _что тут нужно написать ?_ - можно ничего не писать. Не понятно что конкретно ты хочешь узнать: как создать свое событие? ты уже создаешь. Как навесить обработчик своего события? ты уже навешиваешь. Или вопрос только в том, как вызвать это событие?

Comment: вопрос в том как сделать что бы событие срабатывало при appendchild  в этот див

Comment: Нужно самому бросать это событие, в месте, где ты вызываешь `appendChild` у этого дива